# Why isn't firestore showing the logged in user's info?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Background: Login works perfectly, the data is organized like [![this][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Cjq.png
Anytime I log into one of the 2 accounts I made and go to the settings page, it only shows one specific user's info. Lastly, under the .collection("userInfo"), I added .doc(user.uid) and it said that the forEach function was invalid.
Here's the code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    var auth = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
if (user) {
    db = firebase.firestore()
    db
        .collection("userInfo")
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // console.log(user.uid, " => ", doc.data());
                console.log(user.uid)
                var email = doc.data().email;
                var bio = doc.data().bio;
                var downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL;
                document.getElementById("email").placeholder = email;
                document.getElementById("bio").placeholder = bio;
                myimg.src = downloadURL;
              }
         })
```

Comment: When you search by specific doc is not an array the result

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't give an array. But I'm pretty sure it just picks one of the users from the doc id list.

Comment: But why then you expect the forEach function to be in the result as a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var auth = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
   if (user) {
     db = firebase.firestore();
     db.collection("userInfo").doc(user.uid).get()
     .then(function (doc) {
       if(doc.exists) {
         var email = doc.data().email;
         var bio = doc.data().bio;
         var downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL; 
         document.getElementById("email").placeholder = email;
         document.getElementById("bio").placeholder = bio;
         myimg.src = downloadURL;
       }
     });
   }
 });
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I went over it a bit and see that I was wrong in using the forEach function which didn't let me use the .doc() function and I didn't use if (doc.exists). Why did you use that? And thanks so much!

Comment: To make sure that the object exists, sometimes it does not exists because other user deletes it